# Weird Column added to table, trying to work out its origin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a foreign key relationship between two tables and then display information from both using a ViewModel. Unfortunately, it seems Visual Studio has created a weird column called Company_CompanyId in the Person table and I have no idea where it came from to begin with. This has forced me to comment out the "public int CompanyId" from the Person model class as I have ended up with two same columns according to Visual Studio. Anyone able to explain what could force such column to appear?

Person Model

```
public class Person
{

    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    //Foreign Key
    //public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Company Model

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(75)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(75)]
    public string CompanyLocation { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class PersonInCompanyViewModel
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Weird Column]

Thanks

P.S. If you need to see more of my code let me know what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anyone able to explain what could force such column to appear?

When creating a database from a model where you have a Navigation Property, but no Foreign Key Property, EF will create the foreign key column for you.